# Binding to a form encoded dictionary in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

We had a block of code that has been running just fine running in ASP.NET MVC 5, however has stopped working once upgraded to ASP.NET Core. The posted data looks as follows:

[image]

The endpoint (in ASP.NET Core):

```
public IActionResult GetExpressionEditor([FromForm]GetExpressionEditorWidgetModel model)
```

And these are the C# model classes:

```
public class GetExpressionEditorWidgetModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ExpressionEditorViewModel ExpressionEditorData { get; set; }
}

public class ExpressionEditorViewModel
{
    public string Expression { get; set; }

    public IDictionary<string, ExpressionEditorAttribute> SymbolToAttributeMap
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._symbolToAttributeMap == null)
            {
                return new Dictionary<string, ExpressionEditorAttribute>();
            }
            
            return this._symbolToAttributeMap.ToDictionary(entry => entry.Key, entry => ExpressionEditorAttribute.SetDefaults(entry.Key, entry.Value));
        }

        // Default setter
        set { this._symbolToAttributeMap = value; }
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> Data { get; set; }

    private IDictionary<string, ExpressionEditorAttribute> _symbolToAttributeMap;
}
```

The exception I encounter on model binding looks like:

> System.ArgumentNullException
> Error message: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key
>
> at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)
> at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.CollectionModelBinder`1.<BindModelAsync>d__14.MoveNext()   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.DictionaryModelBinder`2.d__7.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ComplexTypeModelBinder.d__10.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ComplexTypeModelBinder.d__10.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder.d__11.MoveNext()

After hours of debugging and trying to step through the internals of model binding, my conclusion is that ASP.NET Core does not like the syntax for the "Data" Dictionary in the form of `expressionEditorData.data.index`, but prefers this syntax:

```
expressionEditorData.data[0].Key = "index"    
expressionEditorData.data[0].Value = 0
```

Is there a way to bind dictionaries using .key = value? Is there another model binder I could be using? or to preserve this functionality - is custom model binding the only way?

Answer (score 0):

you must be upgrading to net6. Net6 has a problem - by default all your properties should be explicitly marked as nullable, or another way is that you can remove a nullable option from a project file

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <!--<Nullable>enable</Nullable>-->
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

or add this line into config (startup or program)

```
services.AddControllers(
options => options.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes = true
```

Comment: I'm actually running ASPNET.Core on Framework 4.7.2. But I'll give that a try

Comment: @badazzhindu You can't run net.core on  net.  It even sounds weird.